# Converting MSXML2.XMLHTTP from Classic ASP to VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, asp-classic

I have a project of converting a ASP classic web page into a VB.NET page and there is this function I'm having a hard time of converting. Please help me what's the equivalent code for VB.NET

```
Function GetSHA1(strKey)
Dim returnString, SoapPara, SoapURL

Set SoapRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0") 
Set myXML =Server.CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")

myXML.Async=False

SoapPara = "Key=" & strKey


If SoapPara <> "" Then

    SoapURL = "http://URL" & SoapPara


    SoapRequest.Open "GET",SoapURL , False 
    SoapRequest.Send()
    if Not myXML.load(SoapRequest.responseXML) then 
        GetSHA1 = "" 
    Else  
        Set nodesDecimal=myXML.documentElement.selectNodes("//string") 
        GetSHA1 = nodesDecimal(0).text
    end if

    Set SoapRequest = Nothing 
    Set myXML = Nothing

End If
End Function

 set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
 set xmlhttp = nothing 

ipay_post_url = chr(34) & "url"  & chr(34)
```

Comment: There isn't an equivalent method.  You can use it in by adding from menu Project : Add Reference : Browse : Then find dll.

Comment: @jdweng what do you mean? There should be something like a code for XML or HTTP GET for vb.net right? That's what I need to know

Comment: It is not a simple one to one equivalency.  You have http, soap, and xml to convert.

Comment: @jdweng please guide me with the correct vb.net code for this

Comment: You may be lucky.  Try Xml Linq  :XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);

Comment: @jdweng Dim myXML As New Xml.XmlDocument worked for me. But how about for this: Set SoapRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")

Comment: That is why I said you may be lucky.  Some XML streaming results will wok with just Xml Linq and other would need a SOAP Request.  Do you need the soap?  Does the SOAP need to be signed?  It gets complicated.